# Java Generics, return generic extending

Tags: java, generics

Why am i not allowed to do this?

```
public abstract class A {}
public class B extends A {}
...

public ArrayList<A> foo()
{
  return new ArrayList<B>();
}
```

I changed to public since there are so many people that love to point stupid errors.

Why should i have to write ALL this code. Just to satisfy Java's non-senses?

```
public List<A> foo() 
{ 
  List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>(); 
  List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
  /* fill bList*/

  for (B b : bList)
  {
    aList.add(b);
  }
  return aList;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An `ArrayList<B>` is not an `ArrayList<A>`. You can't add any arbitrary `A` into it, for example. Or as I like to think of it: a bunch of bananas isn't a fruitbowl. When you try to add an apple to a bunch of bananas, it rolls off...

You can use wildcards to make it work though:

```
public ArrayList<? extends A> foo()
{
    return new ArrayList<B>();
}
```

See the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more details.

EDIT: To answer your specific question of why you need to write all that extra code: you don't. Just create an `ArrayList<A>` within `foo()` to start with. There's no need to copy the contents of one list to another.

If you still object to Java's behaviour, what would you *want* to happen with the following code?

```
// Doesn't compile, fortunately...
List<String> strings = new List<String>();
List<Object> objects = strings;
objects.add(new Date());
String string = strings.get(0); // Um, it's a Date, not a String...
```

Comment: I know wildcards but it messes my superclasses definitions. It's stupid to have to specify 'extends' when you already specified it somewhere else. Whatever ... if i keep on arguing I will be trollified.

Comment: @Gabriel: Well, do you want to force the method to return a genuine `ArrayList<A>` or not? If not, use a wildcard. If so, change the body of the method...

Comment: @Gabriel: And my answer still applies. I've explained why you can't just treat an `ArrayList<B>` as an `ArrayList<A>` - it wouldn't be typesafe to do so.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: typesafe? what are you talking about? if B extends A, i can use B as if it was an A object. There are no castings, no tricky code in the example i posted.

Comment: @Gabriel: See the end of my post for an example of what can go wrong if you expect to be able to treat `ArrayList<B>` as `ArrayList<A>` just because `B` extends `A`.

Answer (score 3):

a) For one thing, `function` does not exist in Java. Java methods have the format

```
modifiers <type_parameters[,type_parameter]*>? return_type method_name (
   [parameter[,parameter]*]?
) [throws exceptiontype[, exceptiontype]*]{ method_body }
```

b) Here's how to do it:

```
public List<? extends A> foo()
{
  return new ArrayList<B>();
}
```

c) I changed the method signature to `List`. It's bad practice to have implementation types in your class' external API if an appropriate interface exists.

Answer (score 2):

because `ArrayList<B>()` is not `ArrayList<A>`. it is not extended from it

`B extends A` **doesn't** mean `ArrayList<B>() extends ArrayList<A>()`